# R - Reticulate won't work with numpy

Tags: python, r, numpy, reticulate

I'm trying to use the Reticulate package to use Python through R. I successfully connected Reticulate to Python 3.6 with `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/usr/local/bin/python3")`. Then after noticing that my Python 3.6 didn't have Numpy, I used entered `pip3 install numpy` into the command line and installed it. Now, I am having the following problem with Reticulate when I call `py_config()`:

```
py_config()
Error in py_run_string_impl(paste0("import sys; sys.path.append('", system.file("python",  : 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nump
```

Uninstalling Numpy fixes the problem, but then I don't have Numpy. :(

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which version (or commit) of 'reticulate' are you using?

Comment: Something might have been wrong for your numpy install. Try reinstall it via `pip install -U --force-reinstall numpy` and see what happens. It would be good to see the output of your `py_config()`.

Comment: The issue is resolved for me. I don't remember what I did. I still see " ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype' " occasionally when I detach and reattach reticulate.

Comment: Perhaps you are not using the numpy from the same Python environment. Try explicitly set your environment using `use_python()`.