# Reticulate not working with numpy 1.13.3

Tags: numpy, reticulate

I am using python 3.6 and numpy 1.13.3. On numpy import, I am getting an error `Cannot import name 'dtype'`

`reticulate::import("numpy")` throws

```
Error in py_run_string_impl(paste0("import sys; sys.path.append('", system.file("python",  : 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype'
```

Should I need to use some old version of numpy to fix this issue

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373082/r-reticulate-wont-work-with-numpy (with more extensive traceback), but no answers there.

Comment: Can you update your quesstion with the output of `py_config()` and `py_discover_config()`? What have you tried from https://rdrr.io/cran/reticulate/f/vignettes/versions.Rmd ?